# How to see the underlying query which includes count() in it, in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in a Django 2 project

```
print(List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).query)
```

which prints the SQL query which is constructed

but the following

```
print(List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count().query)
```

throws error

> print(List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count().query)
>
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'query'

I know why it happens, because `count()` immediately return the count.

**How do I see the query which it constructed**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
```

This line returns count as type `int` and integer type has no attribute query, but you can see the sql query behind this in your django shell

```
from django.db import connection
List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
connection.queries[-1]['sql']
```

`connection.queries` returns list of dictionaries in that shell session.
Also don't name your model `List`. It is a reserved keyword.